# dynamically creating devices in /dev under debian

Tags: debian

I want to build a user space debian service written in C# using dotnet. I intend to use this service to listen for and communicate with IoT switches. I want to expose those switches to the user space applications as folder structure 
`/dev/tyua/switch-A9-0A-42-FE-48-9F` with logical of my own design.

Which set of API calls would I need to learn and use?

Comment: I'd go with Unix sockets.

Comment: Entries in `/dev/` are usually managed by a kernel driver... Unless you already have a working driver for your switches, your approach, using C# and dotnet, can't work: you won't be able to develop a driver using C#. 
Driver are usually develop in standard C but without help of glibc (for example, `printf()` doesn't exist in kernel land). Why do you **absolutely** want to use /dev ? What shall be the behaviour of files under this folder ?

Comment: if not /dev/ then some arbitrary location? I'm not married to the /dev/ idea. Would be nice though.

Comment: Agreed with @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, sockets are what you want.